# Saving grep output to variable changes value

Tags: bash, shell

I want to use `grep` to determine if a string contains a substring. (The plan is to use that result as the test command in a bash `if` statement.)

Here, I check the length of the output of `grep` . :

```
$ echo "abc" | grep "j" | wc -c
       0
```

Since `wc -c` shows zero, I know that `grep` returned an empty string.

But if I save output from `grep` to a variable before calling `wc -c`, I get a different value:

```
$ match=$(echo "abc" | grep "j")
$ echo "$match" | wc -c
       1
```

The output from `grep` now is a string with 1 character in it.

I suspect that it's a newline in there:

```
$ echo $match

$
```

Why is there now an extra character in `$match`, and how can I keep that from happening?

Comment: `echo` prints a newline character and `wc -c` counts it.

Comment: There is no need to use `wc` to do this test.  Just check the value returned by `grep`: `if echo 'abc' | grep -q 'j'; then .... `.

Answer (score 2):

`match` does not contain a newline, but `echo "$match"` writes a newline (but see note below).  In the first case, you are directly passing the output of `grep` to `wc`, but in the second case you are passing the output of `grep` plus a newline to `wc`.

But don't do this at all.  There is no need to introduce `wc` into the problem.  Just test the value returned by grep.  eg:

```
if ... | grep -q "$pattern"; then echo "$pattern was found in the input"; fi
```

Note, `echo "$match"` is bad practice.  For example, consider if `$match` expands to the string `-e` or `-n`. It is much more robust to use `printf '%s' "$match"`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
$ echo "$match" | od -c
0000000  \n
0000001
$ echo "$match" | wc -c
1

$ printf "$match" | od -c
0000000
$ printf "$match" | wc -c
0
```

The only difference in the 2 commands is that `echo` appends a `\n` on the end of the ouput.

Of course, we can make the `printf` generate the same result by explicitly adding a `\n` on the end:

```
$ printf "$match\n" | od -c
0000000  \n
0000001

$ printf "$match\n" | wc -c
1
```